# R call a group of columns by list of index

Tags: r

I am struggling assign values to a matrix. I have the index stored in a list 
 `loc_x`, which is a list of integers. And I am trying to assign numbers to matrix `Nas`, on the columns indexed by `loc_x`. say `loc_x = [1 2 3 5]`, How do I assign 1 to `Nas[1,]` on columns `[1,2,3,5]`?

I tried `Nas[1,c(loc_x)] = 1` or converted `loc_x` to a matrix or array but fails..And I tried to put commas in `loc_x` but also fails.. I know this could be done by a for loop but my dataset is large, so I want to know if there is a efficient way to do this X. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
Nas <- matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow = 2)

loc_x = c(1, 2, 3, 5)

Nas[1, loc_x] <- 1
Nas
#[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0    1
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Explanation: Prior to indexing elements of `Nas`, we initialise the `matrix` with `data = 0` and `ncol` and `nrow`. You will need to adjust the `ncol` and `nrow` values according to your specific situation.

---

If `loc_x` is a `list` you can use `unlist`

```
loc_x <- list(1, 2, 3, 5)
Nas[1, unlist(loc_x)] <- 1
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! But how do I convert loc_x to c(1, 2, 3, 5)? Since it is a quite long list...

Comment: @JINGYAHAN I assumed `loc_x` is already a `numeric` vector. What is the class of `loc_x`?

Comment: @JINGYAHAN If `x_loc` is a `list`, just use `unlist` (see my updated answer).

Comment: @JINGYAHAN If this answers your question, please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.